# I found some weird function signature in glibc, can anyone expain it to me?

Tags: glibc

```
#include <string.h>
#include <memcopy.h>
#include <pagecopy.h>

#undef memcpy

void *
memcpy (dstpp, srcpp, len)
 void *dstpp;
 const void *srcpp;
 size_t len;
{
  unsigned long int dstp = (long int) dstpp;
  unsigned long int srcp = (long int) srcpp;
  ...
```

This is our familiar lib function memcpy's implementation, but I don't recognize its 
signature and I've never seen it before. Can anyone tell me what it is?

Comment: which architecture employs this module? If you've looking besides x86 support, you may find a lot of code looking weird.

Comment: x86 I think. This signature was found in glibc-2.4.

Comment: 'thank you' for what, did you found something architecture-related? I will try to look into problem in newer glibc-2.14

Comment: thank you for your reply. no, I didn't find anything architecture related.

Answer (score 2):

> This is our familiar lib function memcpy's implementation, but I don't recognize its signature

Which aspect of it don't you recognize? Is it the fact that it is written in K&R (pre-ANSI) C, or something else? Would you have recognized it if it was written that way instead:

```
void *
memcpy(void *dstpp, const void *srcpp, size_t len)
{
  ...

}
```

Comment: yes, it is the fact that it is written in K&R C. Thank you. Why this signature is still in use? so weird.

Comment: Because some people think it's more "compatible" or "portable" to keep around constructs that were deprecated 20 years ago and later removed from the language than to use proper C, despite the fact that there's no pre-ANSI compiler with any hope of compiling the majority of the code in glibc.